# Query sequelize table without column 'id'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, backend

I have the following model

**(Migration)** transaction.js

```
    'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('transactions', {
      date: {
        type: Sequelize.DATEONLY
      },
      transNo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
         allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,  
    },
      accNo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('transactions');
  }
};
```

**(Model)** transaction.js

```
  'use strict';
const credit = require('./credit.js'); 
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var transaction = sequelize.define('transaction', {
    date: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    transNo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    accNo: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
  transaction.hasOne(models.credit, {foreignKey: 'transNo'});
    }
    }
  });
  return transaction;
};
```

**(Model)** credit.js

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var credit = sequelize.define('credit', {
    transNo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    creNo: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here

      }
    }
  });
  return credit;
};
```

**(Migration)** credit.js

```
` module.exports = {
      up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.createTable('credits', {
          transNo: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
          },
          creNo: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
          },
          createdAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          },
          updatedAt: {
            allowNull: false,
            type: Sequelize.DATE
          }
        });
      },
      down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
        return queryInterface.dropTable('credits');
      }
    };`
```

it still queries with the id column

Executing (default): SELECT `transaction`.`id`, `transaction`.`date`, `transaction`.`accNo`,.........(and so on).

how to disable the id column from being queried?

Comment: @
Muhammad Suleman Does it work for you?

Comment: @DamienGold No ... the migration file for credit.js
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('credits', {
      ......
      creNo: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true
      },

Answer (score -2):

You simply need to set another column as your primary key and the `id` column won't be generated by default.

```
 module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var credit = sequelize.define('credit', {
    transNo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    {
    creNo: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true //define a primaryKey

    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      }
    }
  });
  return credit;
};
```

Comment: I had made the creNo the primary key in the migrations

Comment: I am following this model syntax as well, although a primary key is defined, the id column is still created.